# Trying to implement backpropagation

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I'm very new to machine learning and am trying to implement gradient descent with back propagation. I have derived the following code. I don't know why its not working...

```
def cost(params,X,y,alpha,lmda):

# first unroll the params
w1=params[0]
b1=1.0   # bias nodes are always 1
w1b=params[1]

w2=params[2]
b2=1.0   # bias nodes are always 1
w2b=params[3]

m=np.double(x.shape[0])

# feed forward
a1=X
z2=np.dot(a1,w1)+b1*w1b
a2=g(z2)
z3=np.dot(a2,w2)+b2*w2b
a3=g(z3)

E=sum(sum((y-a3)**2))/m

# Back propagation
dE=2*(y-a3)

dz3= np.multiply(dE,gPrime(z3))
dw2=sum(np.dot(a2.T,dz3))/m
dw2b=sum(dz3)/m

dz2= np.multiply(np.dot(dz3,w2.T),gPrime(z2))
dw1=sum(np.dot(a1.T,dz2))/m
dw1b=sum(dz2)/m

return E,[w1-alpha*dw1,w1b-alpha*dw1b,w2-alpha*dw2,w2b-alpha*dw2b]
```

Here is my calling function

```
def train(p,X,y,alpha,lmda,iteration):
E=[]
for i in range(iteration):
    print i
    [e,p]=cost(p,X,y,alpha,lmda)
    E.append(e)
print 'cost plot'
plot.plot(E)
plot.show()
return p
```

This is the curve I get when plotting the cost...
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to follow a step-by-step example for back-propagation like this one? https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/
You should be able to check your outputs directly against the numbers given there.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  There was an error when taking the derivative : `dE=-2*(y-a3)`, `dw1=np.dot(a1.T,dz2)`, `dw2=np.dot(a2.T,dz3)` since matrix multiplication does the summation for me.
I did look at the post and put the exact numbers into my neural network, but I get a small deviation from the exact output. `h1,h2:  [0.3825  0.39]  net o1,o2: [1.13593172  1.19546965] outh1,h2:  [ 0.59447593  0.5962827]  outo1,o2: [0.75693192  0.76771788] E1,E2:  [0.27895364  0.02470467]
Etotal:  0.30365831363`. 
Also I'm getting a decreasing curve! Thanks!